# NSURL Always Returns Nil

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurl

I have WCF service and I want to get data from my web service. But URL always returns nil. Why? I want to send parameter to WCF which comes from text field value. For example;

```
txtfield.text = @"ATAŞEHİR";
```

What's wrong ?

```
NSString *request = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/CCWCF.svc/MethodName/%@",txtfield.text];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[request stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
```

I tried different things but result didn't change.

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/CCWCF.svc/MethodName/%@",txtfield.text]];
```

or:

```
NSURL *URL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[request stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
```

Comment: Did you try `NSUTF8StringEncoding` instead (your string seems to be in unicode)?

Comment: @Rajneesh071 please don't use `replaceOccuranceOfString…` for this. The percent escape routines are *far* more capable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSString* encodedText = [txtfield.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *request = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/CCWCF.svc/MethodName/%@",encodedText];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:request];
```

On a separate note, `[NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]` can be a bit problematic for URL encoding. There is a safer way using `Core Foundation`. See http://madebymany.com/blog/url-encoding-an-nsstring-on-ios, for example (can't find the SO question).

Answer (score 1):

You are using `NSASCIIStringEncoding` to encode a unicode string, thus you get weird charaters.

Use `NSUTF8StringEncoding` like:

```
NSString *queryParemeters = [textField.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *request = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/CCWCF.svc/MethodName/%@", queryParemeters];
NSLog(@"Encoded URL :%@", request);
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:request];
```

Comment: That's true, but he should encode only the last part, not the entire URL!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's the unicode characters.
Convert them using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding`:

```
NSString *text = @"ATAŞEHİR";
NSString *convertedText = [text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *request = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/CCWCF.svc/MethodName/%@", convertedText];
```